# Showing message in modal popup after closing another modal popup- Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i'am a beginner in angular. I need to display a success message upon sending an email from modal popup and i'm trying to display the same in another popup.How can i display that?? my code part is

```
<div id="modalViewImportCode" class="modal fade btm-border" role="dialog" style="display:none;" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Email</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >


                    <p>Selectemail</p>

                    <div *ngFor="let primary of email; let i=index;">
                        <div *ngIf="primary">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="margin-5-15">
                                    <span class="pull-left modal3-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="txt{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="primary.Current">
                                        <label for="txt{{i}}"></label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="modal3-checkbox-label clsWordWrap width85per">{{primary.EmailAddress}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="sendMail()" class="btn btn-default">Send Email</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I  tried something like below by butting below div under above code part

```
<div id="modalViewImportCodes" *ngIf="mailSent" class="modal fade btm-border" role="dialog" style="display:none;" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Email</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <p>Sucess</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

sendMail() function triggers the mail.if success then "mailSent" become true.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Jithin,**

> It very simple don't create new dialog, just use SweetAlerts after
>   your AJAX request completion these are very simple and easy. Trying
>   following steps.

**Step 1:**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

**Step 2:**

Place in your desired location and change the message;

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
```

**References:**

> For more options and guidelines use the following URL:

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Regards